# Get ICCID of previously connected SIM

Tags: android

I've lost my SIM card and I need to read messages from it. In order to get a replacement, my carrier requeres me to provide ICCID of lost SIM card, which I don't have.

I have Nexus 4 and lost SIM was connected it in a few days ago. Curretnly there is another SIM in it.

Is there a way to retreive ICCID previously connected SIM? Maybe from some logs, if there are any?

Any solution is accepted.

Comment: 1) I wonder if this question belongs to SO or not. 2) Logs are not kept forever and old ones are continuously purged: unless you had a specific app which stores SIM ICCID's in persistent storage, there is a little less than zero chances to retrieve previous SIM's ICCID.

Comment: I dont think you can get Sim information of the card which is not currently installed and logs are purged after some time.

Answer (score 5):

When android boots up, radio log prints iccid.
This is what I got tested on a Nexus 5 with Android L:

```
adb logcat -v time -b radio | grep -i iccid

09-23 10:50:09.436 D/SIMRecords( 1772): [SIMRecords] iccid: 8986003119110980xxxx
```

By any chance, you still got any log files, just try:

```
grep iccid .
```

---

Another possible shot

This sqlite file also store current iccid in table siminfo:

```
/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/telephony.db
```

If you have backed up this file w/ any tools or pulled out once, try something like this:

```
# sqlite3 telephony.db                                                         
sqlite> select * from siminfo;
```

this is what I got

```
1||0||0|8986003119110980xxxx|1|1|-1|0
```